# Group By Variable in Mongo Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo aggregation which currently ends in this project:

```
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
          subject_id: '$subject.subject',
          groups: '$groups'
        }
      }
```

It creates this array of tests:

```
0:
_id: 1
groups: (27)
name: "Year 1 Maths Paper 1"
subject_id: "111"
1:
_id:2
groups: (27)
name: "Year 1 Maths Paper 2"
subject_id: "111"
```

However, I want to group the data by the subject_id. So each subject will be an array with tests related to it inside. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: see [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage documentation, you can group by `subject_id` and construct array by `$push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-cST7kqFYxS

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to groupby subject_id and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) names to tests array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$subject_id",
      tests: { $push: "$name" }
    }
  }
])
```